# Is this an effective way to compute gradient norm after each epoch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Is this code an effective way to compute the global L2 gradient norm of the model after each training epoch :-

```
current_gradient_norm = nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=float('inf'), norm_type=2.0)
```

I do not want to clip the gradients, I only want to find and store the entire model’s gradient norms after each epoch

Comment: Checkout this [Check the norm of gradients](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/check-the-norm-of-gradients/27961)

Answer (score 0):

the provided code does not compute the global L2 gradient norm of the model after each training epoch. Instead, it uses the `clip_grad_norm_()`. Instead:

```
# Inside your training loop, after each epoch:
model.zero_grad()
# Perform forward and backward pass and compute gradients
loss.backward()

# Compute the global L2 gradient norm
grad_norm = np.sqrt(sum([torch.norm(p.grad)**2 for p in model.parameters()]))
```

Comment: Pytorch's documentation for clip_grad_norm_ states that it returns the "Total norm of the parameter gradients".
I used the documentation as reference to implement my above code, would it be wrong ?

Comment: @StudentV why don’t you check if the two results are the same?

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll try that out